# Set Value to a Report Textbox from a Query

Tags: database, ms-access

I made a query that only shows me a single field and a single record from another query, how can I put that value in a textbox in a report?

The record I want to set is a date that I insert with a MsgBox.

I read that there are ways to just put in the Control Source "=[table]![field]" but I get the Name? error, another way I read but did not understand it is defining a recordset. I can't put the value to the textbox despite trying the ways I've read in other posts.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is with DLookup() domain aggregate function expression in textbox. If field name has space or punctuation/special characters or is a reserved word, [ ] delimiters will be required. Usually table/query name does not but can't hurt.

`=DLookup("[fieldname]","[tableORquery name]")`

Comment: when I use that domain it shows me in the textbox #Error. BTW, I didn´t mention it but the record is a date. I don´t know if that is a reason for the error.

Comment: No, date/time type field should make no difference with the expression. Edit question to show your attempted code. My example said tablename but in your case it would be a query name. Does field name have spaces or special characters (advise not to use either) or is a reserved word? See edited answer.